# Reset dynamic form field issue in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, angular-reactive-forms, dynamicform

I am unable to reset particular form fields in angular. I am attaching here link, where I am trying to achieve, but not working. Please help!!

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-form-fields-q8rm4u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: Which field are you trying to reset?

Comment: any field or both field, but in only one contact at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem here is a misunderstanding of how to use the AbstractControl.reset() method. The value parameter is not related to the controls you want to reset, but the values you want to reset the controls to.

If you change your method to:

```
    resetContact(i: number) {
      this.contacts.at(i).reset();
    }
```

It should work as expected!

Comment: Thanks, and for particular field?

Comment: Then you would have to call reset on that specific field (kinda like acessing within a nested object): this.contacts.at(i).get('yourControl').reset()

Answer (score 1):

Answered it in wrong question (wrong window). Since the solution is not same I am sharing it here.

Instead of index "i" send controls "o" in `resetContact`

```
<button class="btn mx-3 mt-3" (click)="resetContact(o)">Reset</button>
```

Then change the `resetContact()` function as below:

```
 resetContact(o) {        
    o.reset();
    
  }
```

To reset only phone field of a particular control you can use:

```
resetContact(o) {
    o.get('phone').reset();
  }
```

Working demo:

https://angular-dynamic-form-fields-cpoqww.stackblitz.io/

Editor URL:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dynamic-form-fields-cckshh?file=src/app/app.component.ts